# Getting ASCII value of ith character instead of character in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I'm a beginner with Ruby and I'm trying to get a certain character in a string in Ruby like so:

```
string1 = "ohhideraaaa"
puts string1[0]
```

and it's returning 111 rather than "o". I'm sure I'm doing something really stupid, does anyone have any idea what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best fix is to upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3, the current stable release; you are apparently using 1.8.x, where an expression like yours [returns the code of the character at that position](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), but in 1.9.x, it [returns a substring of one character at that position](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), which is what you want.

If upgrading is not an option, or if you would prefer to stick with Ruby 1.8.x, you can persuade it to give you a substring rather than a character-code by specifying a length as well (in your case, `1`):

```
puts string1[0,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.chr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-chr):

```
puts string1[0].chr
```

The `.chr` method converts an ASCII integer value back to a character.